# From scriptlet to Javabean

Tags: jsp, jstl, javabeans, scriptlet

I have the following scriptlet in my JSP:

```
<% for (int i=0; i<emailSettings.qualified_apn.length; i++) { %>
    var g ='<%= emailSettings.qualified_apn[i] %>'
    //some code
<% } %>
```

I moved the variable `emailSettings` into a bean... so now, how do I change the loop?

Comment: `bean.getEmailSettings()`? You should not use scriptlets in a JSP. Learn the JSP EL and the JSTL.

Comment: how do I write the above code in EL and JSTL?

Comment: See the answer of @MikO. Note that you'll need a getter for the `qualified_apn` field. You should never use public fields anyway. Also consider respecting the Java naming conventions: no underscores in variables and methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [**JSTL**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html) to browse the list instead of using scriptlets, which are considered a [**very bad practice**](http://www.theserverside.com/feature/Top-5-reasons-that-JSP-scriptlets-suck)... All the *bussiness logic* should be encapsulated into classes, and the JSP should only contain *presentation logic*...

You should move all your `//some code` to Java classes, and once you have collected into classes all the values you want to show in your page, you can use JSTL like this:

```
<c:forEach var="item" items="${emailSettings.qualified_apn}">
    <p>Item foo: ${item.foo}</p>
    <p>Item bar: ${item.bar}</p>
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

Remember you have to import the JSTL core library into your JSP with:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Also note that, as commented by [**@JBNizet**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356990/converting-into-bean#comment26949896_18356990), you'll need a getter for the `qualified_apn` field in your `EmailSettings` class (you should never use public fields!). Also consider respecting the Java naming conventions: no underscores in variables and methods (i.e., `qualifiedApn`).

I suggest you to start reading through the Oracle's official [**JSTL documentation**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html). Furthermore, you can find many tutorials about JSTL on the web just *googling* "JSTL tutorial", such as on [**tutorialspoint.com**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm).

Comment: how do I do the assignment to variable g?

Comment: @Benny: the var `item` in my code is exactly what your variable `g` is! The tag `forEach` creates a loop that browses your `emailSettings.qualified_apn` list, and in each iteration, the var `item` will contain a member of the list...